# Choosing between Javascript and CSS to handle user events

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been perusing the internet learning more advanced aspects of CSS, and with moderate knowledge of both languages I was able to quickly realize that CSS pseudo-classes are all capable of being performed through javascript event listeners. For example, Javascript has an onfocus event listener that allows you to make changes to controls based on whether or not the user has focused into a textbox, select control, etc. So it comes to a decision of whether it would be better to create a pseudo class in CSS to change the styling of the control, or use javascript to change the class/styling on these events.

My question is, is there a best-practice for this? or is this a situation where it's just best to remain consistent throughout your code but one way is not better than the other? Since Javascript is typically more bloated than CSS, would that make it slightly better to use CSS?

Comment: This is probably a question that will get "opinion based" answers, which is not really the focus of Stack Overflow :)
That said, I personally prefer to handle those things in CSS, since it's more reliable, it doesn't break if JS is disabled and it avoids extra processing (like JS functions to turn classes on/off).
But, as mentioned, this is just a opinion. Maybe giving more details about your project will generate better answers.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. The question itself was borne from pure curiousity, although I did work on a project recently where I had to decide between overwriting an external stylesheet or use jQuery to change styling of select controls on focus. I decided to use jQuery because I was more comfortable with it.

Comment: Re: _"CSS pseudo-classes are **all** capable of being performed through javascript event listeners."_ Maybe not all. In fact, most pseudo-classes describe states which don't correspond to `Events` which can be listened to. (See the full list at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) That's the subtle difference between CSS pseudo-classes and JS Events: the former describe _element states_, while the latter describe _user interactions_.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use CSS instead of Javascript for something simple as changing the styling of the focused element. If you insist on using javascript or if the context is appropriate. It is easier to read and maintain the code if you add/remove classes to change the styling.